# Aspose.Word - Adding rows to an existing table in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, aspose, aspose.words

In a Word template document, I have a table header defined and would like to add data (Multiple rows) to the same table programmatically using aspose and having hard time in doing this.

I found few posts on online for doing this but all of them are written JAVA and functions that are used in these posts are not available in VB.Net.

https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/648997/reg-adding-rows-dynamically-to-the-existing-table-in-the-document.aspx

getLastRow() function doesn't exists in Table Class.(from above post).

Can some one point me to right documentation or provide a solution for my problem.
[image: Missing Width]
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use LastRow method to get last row of table in VB using Aspose.Words for .NET 17.3. Please check complete code as following.

I am Tilal Ahmad, developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
Dim doc As New Document("input.docx")
' Retrieve the first table in the document.
Dim table As Table = DirectCast(doc.GetChild(NodeType.Table, 0, True), Table)
table.FirstRow.RowFormat.HeadingFormat = True
For i As Integer = 1 To 15
' Clone the last row in the table.
Dim clonedRow As Row = DirectCast(table.LastRow.Clone(True), Row)
clonedRow.RowFormat.HeadingFormat = False
' Remove all content from the cloned row's cells. This makes the row ready for
' new content to be inserted into.
For Each cell As Cell In clonedRow.Cells
    cell.FirstParagraph.Runs.Clear() 
    cell.CellFormat.ClearFormatting()
    cell.FirstParagraph.AppendChild(New Run(doc, "hello text"))
Next

' Add the row to the end of the table.

table.AppendChild(clonedRow)
Next

doc.Save("Table.AddCloneRowToTable Out.doc")
```

Comment: this worked when i added 10 rows but its failing after that.

Comment: Exception Message : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Exception Stack:

   at Aspose.Words.Document.(Stream , String , SaveOptions )
   at Aspose.Words.Document.Save(String fileName)
   at WindowsApplication1.IMPlanSetupTest.newpdfgen() in C:\Projects\BFL\Source\BFL.WindowsApplication1\IMPlanSetupTest.vb:line 65

Comment: at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptChildren(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptChildren(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at    .(    )
   at    .(Document , ​   )
   at    .(    ,     )
   at    .      (    )
   at    .      (    )

Comment: at    .(Table , Boolean )
   at    .(Table , Stack , Boolean )
   at    .VisitTableEnd(Table )
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptChildren(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)

Comment: at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at    .(    , Int32 , Boolean )
   at    .(ArrayList , Boolean )
   at    .(ArrayList , Int32 )
   at    .(ArrayList ,    , Int32 , Boolean , Boolean )
   at    . (Table )

Comment: Can you please help me with above exception. I'm trying to add multiple rows (More than 10). Can you share an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Reddy, I am unable to notice any exception while adding 15 rows. I have updated code in my above reply. If issue persists then please share your sample code along with input document, so i will check and guide you accordingly.

Comment: I just tested with other examples and have the same issue. Best way to reproduce this issue is by creating a work document with a table of size 5(Rows)x1(Column) and try adding 99 rows using above code. It is failing with the same exception as above.

Comment: You are getting issue due to evaluation version. Please note the evaluation version of Aspose.Words (without a license specified) provides full product functionality, but it inserts an evaluation watermark at the top of the document on open and save, and limits the maximum document size to several hundred paragraphs. Please make a request for [30 days temporary license](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx) and apply it, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Got It. Thanks.
And how do i repeat table header on each page that this table is displayed?
I tried setting it in word template it self but no luck.

Comment: You can set HeadingFormat property of RowFormat to repeat header row on each new page. I have edited above code for the purpose.